# getting logged in user's detail through session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to make a table where each user/group can see only their data.

so I made each user/group to have their usertype number within user table

```html
+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+
| User_id | username | pwd                                      | usertype |
+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

By getting currently logged in user's usertype through session, I want to make following query for the main data table.

for example if usertype has value of 1, it can see the table with this query( SELECT * FROM table WHERE usertype = '1')

Here is my loginsubmit.php where is submits and starts session

```html
<?php
require_once('php_action/db_connect.php');
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'] ))
{
    $message = 'User is already logged in';
}
if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
} 
else if (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
else if (strlen( $_POST['pwd']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['pwd']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
else if (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
    $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
else {
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pwd = filter_var($_POST['pwd'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pwd = sha1( $pwd );
    
    try {
       
        $sql = "SELECT User_ID FROM User_Dfn WHERE username = '".$username."' AND pwd = '".$pwd."'";
    
        if($result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql)) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $user_id = $row['User_ID'];
                $usertype = $row['usertype'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['usertype'] = $usertype;
                $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
                
                header("Location: index.php");
                
            }
        }
        
        if($user_id == false);
        {
            $message ='Login Failed';
            
            
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) { $message = 'Unable to process request'; }
}
?>
```

And here is a **snippet** of php file where it retrieves the data.

```html
    <?php 

require_once 'db_connect.php';
$usertype= $_SESSION['usertype'];

$output = array('data' => array());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Service WHERE user_id = '$usertype'";
$query = $connect->query($sql);
```

Well, I hope you understood what I wanted to explain, it is a bit complicated for me..

it just doesnt load usertype into sqlquery. I think I am doing something wrong

Please help

Thank you

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: it doesn't load usertype into sql query...

Comment: here `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Service WHERE user_id = '$usertype'";` you are getting problem

Comment: which problem is it?

Comment: You are not getting `$usertype` right?

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `session_start();` in retrieval file

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
<?php 

require_once 'db_connect.php';
session_start();
$usertype= $_SESSION['usertype'];

$output = array('data' => array());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Service WHERE user_id = '$usertype'";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

?>
```

Refer this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I have included it after realised it, still not working as I intended :< thank you anyway

Comment: $usertype seems to be having null value so I think I am loading the data from the database wrong

Comment: write `echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';` after `session_start()`.